# Closed form solution for sum of dice rolls > x

Tags: statistics, dice

I'm trying to figure out a good closed form solution for a problem which I have already simulated and have a rough answer to. The problem is basically rolling 9 dice- each of different face numbers- and seeing the odds of >= a certain sum. This specific example has 55, 28, and 14 sided dice, 3 each. So I roll

3 dice with 55 sides
3 dice with 28 sides
3 dice with 14 sides

and I want to know the odds that the sum is >180

I'm seeing some results for how to calculate the odds of a specific sum online. I'm also seeing the odds of a bracket of options *cenetered around the mean*, but I don't want a bracket centered around the mean. I want the entire right section of the bell curve.

Comment: Nine dice=9 random variables. That means you **cannot** use the bell curve.

Comment: i'm not sure i understand- are you saying because there are more of them their rolls aren't normally distributed? surely they are right?

Comment: If you have a computer, you should be able to manage expanding $(x+x^2+x^3+\dots+x^{55})^3(x+x^2+x^3+\dots+x^{28})^3(x+x^2+\dots+x^{14})^3$.  Looking at the coefficients tells you the number of ways you can achieve those rolls and dividing by $(55\cdot 28\cdot 14)^3$ gives you their respective probabilities.  Adding over the desired range gives the probability you are interested in.

Comment: @user39791 You can use the bell curve if you apply the central limit theorem. One thumb rule is that you have more than 30 random variables. This is not the case at your problem.

Comment: Sums of uniform RVs converge to normal _very rapidly._ You can find the mean and SD for the sum of three 55-sided dice, also for 33-sided and 14-sided dice, Then find the mean and SD for the sum $T$ on all nine rolls You will find that $P(T > 180.5)$ using norm aprx is very nearly the same as the answer from @JMoravitz's exact method. Also, if you simulated with enough iterations you should find your simulated value agrees closely with the exact answer and with the norm approx. I got $P(T > 180) \approx 0.988$ by norm aprx and by sim.w/ $10^7$ reps. I assume this matches your own sim results.

Comment: @BruceET The clt can be only applied with i.i.d random variables. I don´t know how it can be applied in this case.

Comment: @ callculus. There are CLTs in which IID assumption is relaxed in various ways. // As for the speed of convergence for sums of uniform RVs to normal, that is well established. In the early days of computing when current methods of simulating normal RVs from pseudorandom number output were too slow, it was common to simulate std normal variates as the sum of 12 std unif random variables minus 6. While such 'normal' RVs are confined to $(=6, 6),$ output is very hard to distinguish from true std normal by statistical tests. Many of the simulations for the Manhattan Project used this method.

Comment: @BruceET To check if the approximation is good enough it would be nice to know the corresponding coefficient of the generating function.

Comment: Before your last comment: Here is example in which 1000 'standard normal RVs' generated by the 12-uniforms method passes a Shapiro-Wilk test for normally: R code `set.seed(2021); z = replicate(1000, sum(runif(12))-6);  shapiro.test(z)$p.val` returns $0.799282 >> 5\%.$ // To be clear: I am **not recommending** solution by normal aprx or simulation as a substitute for the analytic method; only as a check against making a mistake with the analytic method.